# Is Ethereum the best platform for my project?

Tags: contract-development

I'm a newbie in the blockchain world and I was wondering if I could jog your brains.

I'm currently trying to run a few drones using blockchain and smart contracts, but I'm unsure which platform to host said blockchain on.

I want it to use Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance (or anything safer than crash fault tolerance) and be able to implement smart contracts!

Is Ethereum the way to go? (I've also looked into Hyperledger, but they don't seem to be as active)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Impossible to say. Ethereum could be the best platform if you need it to be widely available (Ethereum has a wide use base) and need very strict decentralized security. But first you should really find out whether your project should use a blockchain at all.

Comment: What does "running drones using blockchain" mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  If you're using drones, you likely need some finality and not to mention centralization around the commands that can be run.  Maybe if you wanted like slow decisions to be made by a DAO it could make sense, but it really just depends.  That said, running a private EVM is probably a great option and you should check out Polygon Edge or there are definitely other options too.